# Difference in hours of two Calendar objects

Tags: java, android, calendar, simpledateformat

I have two `Calendar` objects, and I want to check what is the difference between them, in hours.

Here is the first `Calendar`

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
```

And the second `Calendar`

```
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
c2.setTime(sdf.parse("Sun Feb 22 20:00:00 CET 2015"));
```

Now lets say that `c1.getTime()` is: `Fri Feb 20 20:00:00 CET 2015` and `c2.getTime()` is `Sun Feb 22 20:00:00 CET 2015`.

So is there any code that would return the difference between first and second `Calendar` in hours? In my case it should return `48`.

Comment: If possible, use JodaTime or Java 8's Time API

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
long seconds = (c2.getTimeInMillis() - c1.getTimeInMillis()) / 1000;
int hours = (int) (seconds / 3600);
```

Or using the Joda-Time API's [`Period` class](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html), you can use the constructor `public Period(long startInstant, long endInstant)` and retrieve the hours field:

```
Period period = new Period(c1.getTimeInMillis(), c2.getTimeInMillis());
int hours = period.getHours();
```

Comment: java.time.Period requires API 26 in Android.

Answer (score 10):

In Java 8 you could do

```
long hours = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(c1.toInstant(), c2.toInstant());
```

Comment: java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit requires API 26 in Android.