# Java Parking fee calculations

Tags: java, date, time, calculation, parking

It seems like, I couldn't find the answer for my problem, so here I am, first on Stackoverflow :)

The If statement tree that will be mentioned:

```
buttonSzamol.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            //Változók

                int StartHour = 18;
                int StartMin = 50;
                int StopHour = 20;
                int StopMin = 49;
                int DayTimeIntervalStart = 6;
                int DayTimeIntervalStop = 17;
                int NightTimeIntervalLateStart = 18;
                int NightTimeIntervalLateStop = 23;
                int NightTimeIntervalEarlyStart = 0;
                int NightTimeIntervalEarlyStop = 5;
              int DayHoursTotal = 0;
                int NightHoursTotal = 0;
                int DayTimePricePerHour = Integer.parseInt(NappaliOraDij.getText());
                int NightTimePricePerHour = Integer.parseInt(EjszakaiOraDij.getText());

                int StartDay = Integer.parseInt((DatumStart.getText()).replace(".", ""));
                int StopDay = Integer.parseInt((DatumStart.getText()).replace(".", ""));

                //1 started hour
                if( (StartDay == StopDay) && ( ( (StartHour == StopHour) && (StartMin < StopMin) ) || ( ((StartHour + 1) == StopHour) && (StartMin >= StopMin) ) ) ) {
                    if((DayTimeIntervalStart <= StartHour) && (StopHour <= DayTimeIntervalStop)) {
                        DayHoursTotal++;
                    }
                    if((NightTimeIntervalLateStart <= StartHour) && (StopHour <= NightTimeIntervalLateStop)) {
                        NightHoursTotal++;
                    }
                } else/*More hours*/if( (StartDay == StopDay) && ( ( (StartHour < StopHour) && (StartMin <= StopMin) ) || ( (StartHour < StopHour) && (StartMin > StopMin) ) ) ) {
                    if( (StartHour < StopHour) && (StartMin < StopMin) ) {
                        if((DayTimeIntervalStart <= StartHour) && (StopHour <= DayTimeIntervalStop)) {
                            DayHoursTotal = DayHoursTotal + (StopHour - StartHour);
                            DayHoursTotal++;
                        }
                        if((NightTimeIntervalLateStart <= StartHour) && (StopHour <= NightTimeIntervalLateStop)) {
                            NightHoursTotal = NightHoursTotal + (StopHour - StartHour);
                            NightHoursTotal++;
                        }
                    }else if(( (StartHour < StopHour) && (StartMin >= StopMin) )) {
                        if((DayTimeIntervalStart <= StartHour) && (StopHour <= DayTimeIntervalStop)) {
                            DayHoursTotal = DayHoursTotal + (StopHour - StartHour);
                            if(StartMin != StopMin) {
                                DayHoursTotal--;
                            }
                        }
                        if((NightTimeIntervalLateStart <= StartHour) && (StopHour <= NightTimeIntervalLateStop)) {
                            NightHoursTotal = NightHoursTotal + (StopHour - StartHour);
                            if(StartMin != StopMin) {
                                NightHoursTotal--;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            NappaliOrak.setText(Integer.toString(DayHoursTotal));
            EjszakaiOrak.setText(Integer.toString(NightHoursTotal));
            OrakOsszesen.setText(Integer.toString(DayHoursTotal + NightHoursTotal));
            NappaliOsszeg.setText(Integer.toString(DayHoursTotal * DayTimePricePerHour));
            EjszakaiOsszeg.setText(Integer.toString(NightHoursTotal * NightTimePricePerHour));
            VegOsszeg.setText(Integer.toString((DayHoursTotal * DayTimePricePerHour) + (NightHoursTotal * NightTimePricePerHour)));
        }
    });
```

So, the problem in a nutshell is. 
I've tried to create a parking fee calculator for my colleague at work.
The main idea is, that it needs to calculate how many Daytime and how many Nighttime hours the client started, and it needs to calculate the price of those hours. I've changed the StartHour/Min-StopHour/Min fields to straight integers to be more understanable. I don't know if there is a module for this, but I started doing this with a lot of If statements, where I just got tangled up. In the included pastebin, there is starting time 18:50 and stop time 20:49. If we input this data, the output should be 2 started day hours. Now if the minute is the same, it does not count as a started hour. But if we change the input to 20:51, then it started an another hour, so the DayHoursTotal should be equal to 3.

Thank you in advance, for any help. If you have more questions about my code or idea, just ask.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/aVgVkcz0

Comment: Please provide the most important parts of code in your question, not pastebin.

Comment: So what's your question: To find a simpler way or to correct your code?

Comment: Hey Bence, welcome to StackOverflow. Have you had a look at "Joda time". It is also mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003521/find-total-hours-between-two-dates

Comment: this code looks way to complex. First advice, split it in several method to make it more readable. Easier to read means easier to understand and easier to make it right. Now, out of the blue, I would suggest to use LocalTime (or Joda Time equivalent), then, probably use min/max function to reduce the scope to your boundaries and then duration from LocalTime

Comment: @oerl Not really the time to recommend the otherwise good Joda-Time anymore. From the Joda-Time homepage: “Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310).”

Comment: @OleV.V. Oh...god. Glad you pointed that out. I remove my comment. Thanks Ole!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to calculate the *started* hours not just between 2 **times**, but also between different **dates**.

For this it is best to use the `java.time` package and more specifically the `LocalDateTime` class.

```
LocalDateTime.of(startYear, startMonth, startDay, startHour, startMinute)
```

`LocalDateTimes` in conjuction with the `between()` method from the Java 8 `ChronoUnit` class gets exactly what you need.

```
ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(Temporal t1, Temporal t2)
```

---

PS: You don't need that many '*interval*' variables.
Just the start hour of the *day* (`dayTimeIntervalStart`) and *night* (`nightTimeIntervalLateStart`) rate is enough.
The hours rates before and after can be derived from those two intervals.

---

***Spoiler!! look away if you want to investigate further yourself! ;)***

Here is a runnable code sample that shows the parking logic for >1 day:
(I have omitted the user input parsing/logic, because that depends on your implementation)

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class ParkingFee {

    private static long hoursDifference(LocalDateTime ldt1, LocalDateTime ldt2) {
        long minutesDiff = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(ldt1, ldt2);
        long hoursDiff = Math.round(Math.ceil(minutesDiff/60.0));
        return hoursDiff;
    }

    public static long hoursDifference(
                                int startDay, int startMonth, int startYear, int startHour, int startMinute, 
                                int endDay, int endMonth, int endYear, int endHour, int endMinute) {
        return hoursDifference(
                    LocalDateTime.of(startYear, startMonth, startDay, startHour, startMinute), 
                    LocalDateTime.of(endYear, endMonth, endDay, endHour, endMinute));
    }

    public static int determineDayCycle(int dayTimeIntervalStart, int nightTimeIntervalLateStart) {
        return nightTimeIntervalLateStart - dayTimeIntervalStart;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Hourly rates
        int dayTimePricePerHour = 5;
        int nightTimePricePerHour = 10;

        // Rate intervals
        int dayTimeIntervalStart = 6;
        int nightTimeIntervalLateStart = 18;

        // Counted hours per rate
        int dayHoursTotal = 0;
        int nightHoursTotal = 0;

        // Start date and time
        int startYear = 2019;
        int startMonth = 1;
        int startDay = 1;
        int startHour = 20;
        int startMinute = 50;

        // End date and time
        int endYear = 2019;
        int endMonth = 1;
        int endDay = 3;
        int endHour = 2;
        int endMinute = 49;

        // Calculate the hours difference
        long hourDiff = hoursDifference(
                startDay, startMonth, startYear, startHour, startMinute, 
                endDay, endMonth, endYear, endHour, endMinute);
        System.out.println("Hour difference found: "+ hourDiff);

        // Handle parking for full days
        if (hourDiff > 24) {
            int dayCycle = determineDayCycle(dayTimeIntervalStart, nightTimeIntervalLateStart);
            long fullDays = hourDiff / 24;
            nightHoursTotal += (24-dayCycle)*fullDays;
            dayHoursTotal += dayCycle*fullDays;
            hourDiff = hourDiff % 24;
        }

        // Handle the parking for less than full day
        while (hourDiff > 0) {
            if (startHour < dayTimeIntervalStart) { // Before the day interval -> night
                nightHoursTotal++;
            } else if(startHour < nightTimeIntervalLateStart) { // Before the night interval -> day
                dayHoursTotal++;
            } else { // After the day interval -> night
                nightHoursTotal++;
            }
            startHour++;
            if (startHour > 23) // At midnight reset the hour to 0
                startHour = 0;
            hourDiff--;
        }

        System.out.println("Day hours: "+ dayHoursTotal);
        System.out.println("Night hours: "+ nightHoursTotal);
        System.out.println("Total hours: "+ (dayHoursTotal + nightHoursTotal));
        System.out.println("Day rate charged at "+ dayTimePricePerHour +": "+ (dayHoursTotal * dayTimePricePerHour));
        System.out.println("Night rate charged at "+ nightTimePricePerHour +": "+ (nightHoursTotal * nightTimePricePerHour));
        System.out.println("Total rate charged: "+ ((dayHoursTotal * dayTimePricePerHour) + (nightHoursTotal * nightTimePricePerHour)));
    }
}
```

This outputs:

> Hour difference found: 30
>   Day hours: 12
>   Night hours: 18
>   Total hours: 30
>   Day rate charged at 5: 60
>   Night rate charged at 10: 180
>   Total rate charged: 240

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to parse the Integers differently. Your method is dangerous, e.g. loses information. Plus you need to make the code failsafe in case somebody tries to put in values that won't work. Refer to this question: [How do I convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java)

Apart from that, working with just minutes and hours is always difficult. I suggest using the absolute times in milliseconds which makes it far easier to do calculations. Refer to this question: [Difference in hours of two Calendar objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651107/difference-in-hours-of-two-calendar-objects)

Comment: My main thing would be to first calculate the differences correctly. After that I can check for any possible bad inputs, or parsing the things correctly. First objective of mine, is to get the "Hours started" first. This millisecond approach could be good. Giving it a go, and telling you the results afterwards!

Comment: Don’t use milliseconds, that’s too low-level, and don’t use `Calendar`, that class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead I recommend `LocalTime` and `Duration` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

*divide et impera*

Cutting down the big logic in small blocks make it easier to achieve

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;

class Scratch {
    static int StartHour = 18;
    static int StartMin = 50;
    static int StopHour = 20;
    static int StopMin = 48;
    static int DayTimeIntervalStart = 6;
    static int DayTimeIntervalStop = 17;
    static int NightTimeIntervalLateStart = 18;
    static int NightTimeIntervalLateStop = 23;
    static int NightTimeIntervalEarlyStart = 0;
    static int NightTimeIntervalEarlyStop = 5;
    static int DayTimePricePerHour = 10;
    static int NightTimePricePerHour = 5;
    static LocalTime dayStart = LocalTime.of(DayTimeIntervalStart, 0);
    static LocalTime dayStop = LocalTime.of(DayTimeIntervalStop, 0);
    static LocalTime nightEarlyStart = LocalTime.of(NightTimeIntervalEarlyStart, 0);
    static LocalTime nightEarlyStop = LocalTime.of(NightTimeIntervalEarlyStop, 0);
    static LocalTime nightLateStart = LocalTime.of(NightTimeIntervalLateStart, 0);
    static LocalTime nightLateStop = LocalTime.of(NightTimeIntervalLateStop, 0);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(2019, 1, 1, StartHour, StartMin);
        LocalDateTime stop = LocalDateTime.of(2019, 1, 1, StopHour, StopMin);

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            stop = stop.plusMinutes(1L);
            System.out.println(process(start, stop));
            System.out.println("******");
        }

        stop = stop.plusDays(1L);
        System.out.println(process(start, stop));
        System.out.println("******");

    }


    public static int process(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime stop){
        System.out.println(String.format("checking between %s and %s", start, stop));
        if(stop.toLocalDate().isAfter(start.toLocalDate())){
            // start and stop not on the same date
            // split the computation, first currentDay then the rest
            LocalDateTime endOfDay = LocalDateTime.of(start.toLocalDate(), LocalTime.MAX);
            int resultForCurrentDay = process(start, endOfDay);

            // not for the rest
            LocalDateTime startOfNextDay = LocalDateTime.of(start.toLocalDate().plusDays(1L), LocalTime.MIN);
            int resultForRest = process(startOfNextDay, stop);
            return resultForCurrentDay + resultForRest;
        }else{
            // start and stop on the same date
            return processIntraDay(start, stop);
        }
    }

    private static int processIntraDay(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime stop) {
        int result = 0;
        LocalTime startTime = start.toLocalTime();
        LocalTime stopTime = stop.toLocalTime();

        // step 1: check early morning
        result += checkBoundaries(startTime, stopTime, nightEarlyStart, nightEarlyStop, NightTimePricePerHour);

        // step 2: check day time
        result += checkBoundaries(startTime, stopTime, dayStart, dayStop, DayTimePricePerHour);


        // step 3: check late night
        result += checkBoundaries(startTime, stopTime, nightLateStart, nightLateStop, NightTimePricePerHour);

        return result;
    }

    private static int checkBoundaries(LocalTime startTime, LocalTime stopTime, LocalTime lowerBoundary, LocalTime upperBoundary, int priceRatePerHour) {
        // check if the period [start;stop] is crossing the period [lowerBoundary;upperBoundary]
        if(stopTime.isAfter(lowerBoundary) && startTime.isBefore(upperBoundary)){
            // truncate start time to not be before lowerBoundary
            LocalTime actualStart = (startTime.isBefore(lowerBoundary))?lowerBoundary:startTime;

            // symetrically, truncate stop to not be after upperBounday
            LocalTime actualStop = (stopTime.isAfter(upperBoundary))?upperBoundary:stopTime;

            // now that we have the proper start and stop of the period, let's compute the price of it
            return compute(actualStart, actualStop, priceRatePerHour);
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private static int compute(LocalTime startTime, LocalTime stopTime, int pricePerHour) {
        Duration duration = Duration.between(startTime, stopTime);
        int hours = (int) duration.toHours();
        long minutes = duration.toMinutes();
        if(minutes % 60 > 0L){
            // hour started, increasing the number
            hours++;
        }
        int result = hours * pricePerHour;
        System.out.println(String.format("%d hours at %d price/h => %d", hours, pricePerHour, result));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Went directly for the calculation of the final price. Updating to store total number of day hours and night hours should be much of a challenge

Result of my exemple:

```
checking between 2019-01-01T18:50 and 2019-01-01T20:49
2 hours at 5 price/h => 10
10
******
checking between 2019-01-01T18:50 and 2019-01-01T20:50
2 hours at 5 price/h => 10
10
******
checking between 2019-01-01T18:50 and 2019-01-01T20:51
3 hours at 5 price/h => 15
15
******
checking between 2019-01-01T18:50 and 2019-01-02T20:51
checking between 2019-01-01T18:50 and 2019-01-01T23:59:59.999999999
5 hours at 5 price/h => 25
checking between 2019-01-02T00:00 and 2019-01-02T20:51
5 hours at 5 price/h => 25
11 hours at 10 price/h => 110
3 hours at 5 price/h => 15
175
******
```

Might need more tests to ensure it's good in all conditions but should be a usefull starting point for you

Comment: might have to tweak a little bit around midnight to not count that hour twice which is probably the case in my code.

Comment: Gonna check it out, but seems like this is what I'm looking for! 
Thank you man! If it solves, I'm gonna mark yours as "The Answer"

Answer (score 0):

## Time Zone

Your code and the other Answers fail to account for [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) anomalies. If you are tracking actual moments, when people actually parked, as opposed to theoretical 24-hour long days, then you must account for anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). Politicians around the world have shown a penchant for redefining the time zone(s) in their jurisdiction. So days can be any length, such as 25-hours long, 23-hours, 23.5 hours, 24.25, or others.

A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) used by the people of a particular region.

The `LocalDateTime` class is exactly the wrong class to use for this purpose. That class intentionally has no concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. You can use it as a building block piece in your code, but it must be assigned a `ZoneId` to determine an actual moment via the `ZonedDateTime` class.

### `ZoneId`

Specify your time zone.

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument. If critical, confirm the zone with your user.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

### Assemble date, time, & zone to determine a moment

Assemble your date and time-of-day.

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of( 2019 , 1 , 23 ) ;  // 23rd of January in 2019.
LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.of( 18 , 50 ) ;  // 6:50 PM.
ZonedDateTime startMoment = ZonedDateTime.of( startDate , startTime , z ) ;

LocalDate stopDate = LocalDate.of( 2019 , 1 , 23 ) ;  // 23rd of January in 2019.
LocalTime stopTime = LocalTime.of( 20 , 50 ) ;  // Two hours later, exactly — maybe! Depends on any anomalies at that time in that zone.
ZonedDateTime stopMoment = ZonedDateTime.of( stopDate , stopTime , z ) ;
```

➥ Note that in this example, we *may* have a span of time of exactly 2 hours, but *maybe not*. It might be 3 hours or some other length of time, depending on anomalies scheduled for that date at that time in that zone.

## Elapsed time

To calculate elapsed time it terms of days (24-hour chunks of time, unrelated to the calendar), hours, minutes, and seconds, use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html). (For year-months-days, use `Period`.)

```
Duration d = Duration.between( startMoment , stopMoment ) ;
```

Interrogate for entire span-of-time in terms of whole hours.

```
long hours = d.toHours() ;  // Entire duration as count of whole hours.
```

## Half-Open

> In the included pastebin, there is starting time 18:50 and stop time 20:49. If we input this data, the output should be 2 started day hours. Now if the minute is the same, it does not count as a started hour. But if we change the input to 20:51, then it started an another hour, so the DayHoursTotal should be equal to 3.

This approach is know as *Half-Open*, when the beginning is *inclusive*, while the ending is *exclusive*. This is commonly used in date-time handling. The `Duration` and `Period` classes apply this approach.

But be careful about matching the minute number alone. Your date-time objects might be holding seconds and/or a fractional second, which would throw off your algorithm. As a habit, truncate your date-time objects explicitly if there is any possibility of smaller granularity than you want. For example, [`ZonedDateTime.truncatedTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)).

## Rate changes

Obviously, rate changes complicate matters. The other Answers seem to have covered this, so I'll not repeat. But I can add a big tip: See the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) for its classes `Interval` and `LocalDateRange` that may be of help to you. They include handy comparison methods for overlaps, contains, abuts, and so on.

Comment: I thank you for this long and explanatory comment. The timezone approach could be used, but this is just a simple program to help one of my colleague. No need for overcomplicating, since they just gather the times in an excel, and after that, they just do calculations by hand in a calculator. So if this would be a bigger project, these would be things to be account for :) Thank you again, I've learnt a lot of things from your comment now :)